# Abuse of DMCA for content licensed under CC BY and recourse

Tags: creative-commons, dmca

There was a video of a county's legislative session posted by their authorized film company posted on YouTube under **CC BY**. A guy then downloaded it and reposted it on his YouTube channel with **attribution.**

A few days later a representative of company, who made the film changed the licence, took down video on his own channel and contacted the guy who reposted the film and demanded takedown from guy's channel. He refused. Afterwards he sent DMCA and video got removed.

Now does the guy have any legal recourse for having to file counter notice and expenses occured or a right to punitive damages? Shouldn't have YouTube prevented a DMCA takedown if content was shared under a CC BY licence?

Can he also be sued for something as the guy whose video got taken down had a valid **irrevocable** licence and the copyright owner was obviously aware of that?

Comment: Does the guy have any evidence that the license was changed and, more importantly, of the original license terms?

Comment: He does have a screenshoot of original video where the licence is clearly stated as CC BY

Comment: Can you post a link to the screenshot?  Would help clear up any ambiguities.  Everyone involved in the USA?

Comment: @matthew That's unnecessary. We can take the factual assertions in this question at face value and give an answer under the assumption that those facts are true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DMCA allows for a counter-notice. You can submit a counter-notice with a statement that you have a licence to distribute the content. Statements in the counter-notice about the facts relating to your permission to reproduce are under penalty of perjury.

You could also sue the content owner to attempt to get an injunction against future takedown requests and you could get costs (not punative damages) awarded under 17 USC 512(f).

Comment: I do know about counter-notice. That is not in question. Problem is issuing DMCA takedown request knowing that poster of video had a valid licence for it.

Comment: I wouldnt make assumptions about what the DMCA filer knew. Regardless, your recourse is either DMCA counter notice and/or a law suit or agreement to prevent future takedowns.

Comment: He changed the licence just before requesting removal.

Comment: @chanthunder okay.

Comment: "Statements in the counter-notice are under penalty of perjury" Not all statements, just that they represent copyright owner. 
"DMCA expressly does not require the sender of a notice to certify under penalty of perjury that they have correctly identified the complained-of file as one of their works. A takedown notice’s “[i]dentification of the copyrighted work claimed to have been infringed” is not made under penalty of perjury. 17 U.S.C. § 512(c)(3)(A)(ii)."

Comment: That is with respect to the original notice. In the counter notice, your assertion of facts relating to your permission to reproduce are subject to penalty of perjury. I don't see how this changes anything.

Comment: There is also 17 U.S.C § 512(f)

Comment: @chanthunder Just to add, it's possible that the original film was not allowed to be licensed under the Creative Commons license, because they did not have the permission. In such a case, they have to change the license, and they may be require to take down anything from that. I'm a little shaky on this though

Comment: @Zizouz212 It's a public session. Also videos from other sessions are posted under CC.